# Spark Ingestion path: "Source to Driver to Worker" or "Source to Workers"

Tags: apache-spark

When Spark ingest the Data, is there specific situation where it has to go trough the driver and then from the driver the worker ? Same question apply for a direct read by the worker.

I guess i am simply trying to map out what are the condition or situation that lead to one way or the other, and how does partitioning happen in each case.

Answer (score 1):

If you limit yourself to built-in methods then unless you create distributed data structure from a local one with method like:

- `SparkSession.createDataset`
- `SparkContext.parallelize`

data is always accessed directly by the workers, but the details of the data distribution will vary from source to source.

RDDs typically depend on Hadoop input formats, but Spark SQL and data source API, are at least partially independent, at least when it comes to configuration,

It doesn't mean data is always properly distributed. In some cases (JDBC, streaming receivers) data may still be piped trough a single node.